# Removing Object/Movie Clip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I'm fairly new at Actionscript 3. This will just be a quick question.


How can I remove a Movie Clip from the stage if I, for example, click on it? I didn't use `addChild()` or Sprites. I manually put it on the stage.

*Sorry if my explanation is bad or vague

Comment: It is not important that you didn't use **addChild**. There's no difference. You just remove the clicked object from its **parent**.

Comment: From it's parent? you mean the stage? Sorry for asking this. I got the first part but I don't what/who the parent is if I manually put the MC to the stage from the library

Comment: Every object you see has a property **parent** which points to its parent object on the display list. Say, you have an **A** object, then removing it will go as **A.parent.removeChild(A);** if you are not sure what its parent is.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  To get the best answer possible, please edit your question to include the relevant code you're using.  Also give the full error message.    1009 means that the object you're referencing doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the "Sprites" aka Movieclips over code, you have to implement, the addChild() functionality in your code. After that, you can remove that with stage.removeChild(Moveclipname). Thats all.

Comment: if you want to remove that movieclip from stage, where you added it manuall, look at the name of that movieclip you registered and use stage.removeChild(thenameofyourmovieclipyouadded);

Comment: You can remove timeline created instances from the stage through code just fine.  They *may*, however, get recreated and added back the next time that timeline gets instantiated or *possibly* when the timeline loops (if it loops).